# uploading of files

Tags: c#, wcf, file-upload

I am working on uploading files with a WCF web service,
here's my code for uploading:

```
public string UploadTransactionsFile(string uploadPath)
{
    string uploadTransactionsFile;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadPath))
        return string.Empty;

    if (!ValidateTransactionsFile(uploadPath))
        return string.Empty;

    try
    {
        var dir = @"C:\Upload\";
        string myUploadPath = dir;
        var myFileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadPath);
        CheckDirectory(myUploadPath);

        var client = new WebClient { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials };
        client.UploadFile(myUploadPath + myFileName, "PUT", uploadPath);
        client.Dispose();

        uploadTransactionsFile = "ok";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        uploadTransactionsFile = ex.Message;
    }

    return uploadTransactionsFile;
}
```

I created a Windows Forms test client and added the service reference, but
my code in calling the method and hardcoded the file i want to upload:

```
private testServiceClient testService;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var File = "C:\\file.csv";
    testService = new testServiceClient();

    testService.UploadTransactionFile(File);
}
```

I can upload files using one computer, but when I put my test client to another computer, then I can't, because the file is just passing the stringpath, which cannot be found on server computer.

Am I missing something?

Do I have to send my file as `byte[]`? If so, then how do I do this?

Comment: Yes, you need to send the **content** of your file. The *distant* computer does not have access to your file system (fortunately) and it will clearly search for a local path.

Comment: See my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18872534/2206468 Will get you idea on how to go about using wcf for uplaods, else like Hugh said, you can just upload files from client using webclient alone.

Comment: when you said content you're talking about byte[]? sorry, i don't know much with this, can you give me link or reference on how can i work with it?

Comment: You can also send it as a `stream` : [one example here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx) and [another example here](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/08/28/file-transfer-with-wcp/)

Comment: question sir, why can't i find my web service when i change network with two computer?

Comment: That is another question and there could be numerous factors. I suggest you to proceed step by step, I mean once your service works as you want (on the same computer for example so you can test it), then you can try to deploy it so it can be accessible from other computers.

Comment: one other way to avoid sending big files/data from client to/fro wcf is to expose a ftp share (or network shared folder) and design your system such that client needs to upload files there and invoke a method of wcf by just passing path or name of newly created file or files and let wcf read it from there. This saves lot of bandwidth required between client and wcf for wcf calls and so wcf can take more number of such requests and will be better performing for even huge files, also can upload many files in one go this way passing collection of file names/path.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: yes sir, thanks for the help guys, your link provided helps me,thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

To stream files over HTTP to WCF service:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

However, WebClient class is designed to be used on the client side too. So you could bypass the WCF service altogether.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx):

> Provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a
>   resource identified by a URI.